# Cannot use agent class in fuelphp

Tags: php, fuelphp

I'm trying to get agent info by agent class

```
$user_agent = Fuel\Core\Agent::browser();
echo $user_agent;
```

but this doesn't work and I get 'unknown'

In logs, I've got this error.

```
Agent::parse_browscap - Failed to download browscap.ini file.
Agent::parse_browscap - Failed to get the cache of browscap.ini file.
```

I've checked confing/agent.php.

```
    'browscap' => array(
                  'enabled' => true,
                  'url' => 'http://browscap.org/stream?q=Full_PHP_BrowsCapINI',   // complete file, approx. 3 times the lite version
                  'method' => 'wrapper',
                  'file' => '/tmp/php_browscap.ini',
),
```

URL is right(also in /config/class/agent.php).

What is wrong with my php?

Comment: The problem is that for some reason you cannot download the browscap file (error 1) and there is no cached version (error 2). Try setting the method to curl to see if there is something wrong with your PHP settings. If that doesn't work you can download the file manually, set the method to local and the file to the path you downloaded it.

Comment: THANKS a lot.Curl　didn't work, so I downloaded the file manually and used if.

Comment: It is perfectly fine as the agent would download it anyway. This way you have greater control over what you are doing. However you have two further options: investigate what causes the issue (fuel bug or your environment) or you can use a completely different library. There are quite a few awesome agent libraries on packagist. Fuel v2 will not be shipped with one out of the box.